# Android Studio showing and hiding fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making a quiz app where flags are displayed on the left hand side of the screen, and when pressing them, you have to guess which country it belongs to in a `Fragment` on the right hand side of the screen. So when pressing a flag, you should be taken to a `Fragment` where you can input your answer. Aka each flag has its own `Fragment`. However, I'm having some problems with the code.

No matter which one of the buttons(/flags) I click, all the fragments show up at once. However, I just want them to appear one at a time. I have tried inserting an if statement in my code, but I feel like I'm missing something. 
Would appreciate all help!

Would a solution be to add `.show()` and `.hide()` inside the if statements?

**Play.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import layout.FragmentOne;
import layout.FragmentTwo;

public class Play extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    final ImageButton imageBtn10 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);
    imageBtn10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      {
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
                 FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
                 FragmentOne f1 = new FragmentOne();
                 fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place, new FragmentOne());
                 fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                 fragTrans.commit();
           }
    });

    final ImageButton imageBtn9 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);
    imageBtn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      {

           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(v.equals(imageBtn9)) {               
                 FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
                 FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
                 FragmentTwo f2 = new FragmentTwo();
                 fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_place2, new FragmentTwo());
                 fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                 fragTrans.commit();
                                      }
           }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to add something like fragTran.show() and fragTran.hide() into the if statements?

Comment: Your `onClick` listener changes fragments in two different containers.. If you need them to replace each other use the same container

Comment: @akash93 Am I on the right track with the code in the comment below?

Comment: No I meant your fragment Transaction replaces the fragment in `R.id.fragment_place` for the first case and `R.id.fragment_place2` in the 2nd case.  They need to be in the same container if you need them to replace each other